# Making a particular document list or library mandatory to show in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

Can I have a particular List or Library Document be always available in the top, no matter how many document we add or modify?

Example: Document 1 should always be shown, no matter we keep adding n number of document. Even if we use Document 1 or not it should be available as the top and viewable in SharePoint 2010.

Can you any provide suggestions if that is possible if so please do answer.

Comment: Make a Yes/No column on the library. Call it "sticky". Configure your views to show "sticky" items first.

Comment: How do I do that? I can create the columns but i am unable to select to show that first

Comment: This does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Yes/No column. Call it "sticky" or whatever makes sense in your environment. Then configure your views to sort by the "sticky" field. Go to the list ribbon and click "Modify View". In the sorting options choose to sort by "sticky". Your "sticky" items will always show up first:
[image]

Comment: But I guess doing this for example "Sticky" will always appear when uploading the document which can confuse them. Sorry if I am wrong

Comment: Yes it will, unless you hide it from the forms.

Comment: To be true, I dont know how to hide it from the form, can you guide me please.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it and it worked. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. If you still want help hiding that field on the form, ask a new question here.